# RxJava как дождаться выполнения запроса в RxJava и во время выполнения не вызывать его снова?

Tags: java, android, rxjava, rxjava2

Вопрос в следующем, как дождаться выполнения запроса в RxJava и во время выполнения не вызывать его снова?

Или же например вызывать, но обрабатывать результат только последнего, а предыдущих игнорировать.

Предпочтительнее конечно варианты решения методами самой RxJava. Спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: Так Вы приведите хоть код какой-то. Ну а вообще есть такая штука как `switchMap` [статейка, где про него говорится](https://medium.com/appunite-edu-collection/rxjava-flatmap-switchmap-and-concatmap-differences-examples-6d1f3ff88ee0)

Comment: а код только в заблуждение введет, я наоборот не стал его приводить) а цель именно такая как я описал)

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее простые два решения:

1. Решение средствами `RxJava`, метод `switchMap`

   Без использования `switchMap`  (метод `flatMap`):

   ```
   @Test
   public void flatMap() throws Exception {
       final List<String> items = Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");

       final TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();

       Observable.from(items)
               .flatMap( s -> {
                   final int delay = new Random().nextInt(10);
                   return Observable.just(s + "x")
                           .delay(delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS, scheduler);
               })
               .toList()
               .doOnNext(System.out::println)
               .subscribe();

       scheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
   }
   ```

   > Вывод в результате запуска: [cx, ex, fx, bx, dx, ax]

   С использованием `switchMap`  (вместо метода `flatMap`):

   ```
   @Test
   public void flatMap() throws Exception {
       final List<String> items = Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");

       final TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();

       Observable.from(items)
               .switchMap( s -> {
                   final int delay = new Random().nextInt(10);
                   return Observable.just(s + "x")
                           .delay(delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS, scheduler);
               })
               .toList()
               .doOnNext(System.out::println)
               .subscribe();

       scheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
   }
   ```

   > Вывод в результате запуска: [fx]

   Необходимо отметить, что в данном случае выполняться будет только последний запрос, предыдущие при повторном вызове будут прерываться.
2. Решение "костыльное", своими силами.

   Изначальный код тот же.

   ```
   @Test
   public void flatMap() throws Exception {
       final List<String> items = Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");

       final TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();

       bool flag = false;

       Observable.from(items)
               .filter(s -> { return !flag } )
               .doOnNext(s -> {flag = true })
               .flatMap( s -> {
                   final int delay = new Random().nextInt(10);
                   return Observable.just(s + "x")
                           .delay(delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS, scheduler);
               })
               .toList()
               .doOnNext(System.out::println)
               .doOnComplete( { flag = false })
               .subscribe();

       scheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
   }
   ```

   > Вывод в результате запуска: [ax]

   Второй способ не начнет исполнение нового запроса, если еще выполняется старый.

Код написан на коленке, если видите опечатки / ошибки - комментируйте и исправляйте)